# Issues with Sinatra and Ruby 1.9.2 on Shotgun

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, sinatra

I have a simple sinatra app.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  "Hello"
end
```

When I run it on Shotgun I get the following error:

> Boot Error
>
> Something went wrong while loading
>   simple.rb
>
> LoadError: no such file to load --
>   simple.rb
>
> :29:in
>   `require'
>   <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in`
>   require'
>   /home/thedinga/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/shotgun-0.8/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:114:in
>   `inner_app'
>   /home/thedinga/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/shotgun-0.8/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:102:in`
>   assemble_app'
>   /home/thedinga/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/shotgun-0.8/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:86:in
>   `proceed_as_child'
>   /home/thedinga/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/shotgun-0.8/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:31:in`
>   call!'
>   /home/thedinga/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/shotgun-0.8/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:18:in
>   `call'
>   /home/thedinga/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/shotgun-0.8/lib/shotgun/favicon.rb:12:in`
>   call'
>   /home/thedinga/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:77:in
>   `call'
>   /home/thedinga/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in`call'
>   /home/thedinga/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in
>   `service'
>   /home/thedinga/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in`
>   service'
>   /home/thedinga/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in
>   `run'
>   /home/thedinga/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in`
>   block in start_thread'

If i were to use `ruby simple.rb` instead of shotgun, I get the output you'd expect in a browser. As a sidenote, if I push it to Heroku (which I would really like to run a sinatra app on), Heroku will fail to run the app as well. Is this a version issue with 1.9.2 ? or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the code above works, just correct require '#{path}/myapp' at config.ru file to require "#{path}/myapp" .

In ruby just strings with " caracter can use inner #{}. In string with ' caracter the string will be continue being '#{path}/myapp' and not 'value/of/path/variabel/myapp'.

So it can be done like the following

```
# FILE config.ru

path = File.expand_path "../", __FILE__

require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require "#{path}/myapp"

run Sinatra::Application


# FILE myapp.rb

get '/' do
  'hello'
end
```

star the application just running the command shotgun at app root directory

Comment: wow thanks for the tip, I'm a .Net guy so I wont catch things like that.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try decoupling the config from the app itself?

My template is something like

```
# FILE config.ru

path = File.expand_path "../", __FILE__

require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require '#{path}/myapp'

run Sinatra::Application


# FILE myapp.rb

get '/' do
  'hello'
end

# FILE start.sh

shotgun -o 0.0.0.0 -p 8888 &
```

This with ruby1.9.2-p0..

Comment: Ok so I gave this a try with no success. I'm pretty new to ruby in general so I have a couple of questions. 1. Should config be config.ru? 2. I'm not familiar with whats going on in the start.sh file. Does that replace `shotgun config.rb` command?

Comment: what problem are you getting?

Comment: The browser is throwing the same error: LoadError: no such file to load -- config.rb

Comment: 1. yes, it should have been `config.ru`, just a typo. 2. the start.sh is just a convenience script, it replaces the call to shotgun. Of course you need to `chmod +x start.sh` before executing it..

Comment: So this is the output now `LoadError: no such file to load -- #{path}/simple`

Comment: all these files should be in the same directory, I just tried your example and it worked.

Comment: Would sinatra 1.1 have anything to do with it?

Comment: I saw just now the problem, sorry, I wrote it entirely by hand without copying and I missed the double quote string..

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix for this is discussed on the [shotgun issues page on github](https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun/issues#issue/26).

```
$ shotgun -I. simple.rb
```

Answer (score 1):

My `config.ru` is typically much simpler:

```
root = ::File.dirname(__FILE__)
require ::File.join( root, 'app' )

# Assuming your application is subclassed from Sinatra::Application
run MyApp.new
```

The `app.rb` file can (and should) require Sinatra (and rubygems if you're not on 1.9).

Comment: This works for me in 1.8.7 and 1.9.2. This is the most versatile answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2 and Sinatra and I also have problems running it with Shotgun. There's a simple workaround: use `sinatra-repeater` gem instead of Shotgun. Installation and setup is described in Sinatra Book: http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/#automatic_code_reloading